Postfix smtpd_sender_login_maps, check for LDAP and a manually created list
I have enabled SASL on my Postfix server and have placed an LDAP configuration file for smtpd_sender_login_maps. It currently looks like this:
ldap_sender_login_maps.cf
server_host = AD.SERVER.com
server_port = 389
version = 3
bind = yes
start_tls = no
bind_dn = CN=USER,OU=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com
bind_pw = ******
search_base = DC=DOMAIN,DC=com
scope = sub
query_filter = (&(|(userPrincipalName=%s)(mail=%s))(objectClass=person)(!(userAccountControl=514)))
result_attribute= userPrincipalName
debuglevel = 0

Thus, User A is only allowed to send emails with the email addresses stored in AD. However, I would like to configure it further to allow exceptions, for example, for shared mailboxes. User A should also be able to send from an email address that is not in their AD but is listed in another config file. This involves several hundred users, so it should be stored somewhere efficiently.
I have already tried many things, such as using unionmap or trying to write my own small scripts. Nothing has worked well.
Like this:
main.cf
smtpd_sender_login_maps = unionmap:{ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-sender-login.cf, hash:/etc/postfix/shared-mailboxes}
shared-mailboxes
userA@example.com    shared-mailbox@example.com
But this doesnt work...
I would be very grateful for any suggestions!
